# Can I create an ASP MVC master-details with several models on a single master view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Lets say I have a master view `InvoiceMaster`.

I want that view to to contain 2 others partial views at the same time. Those are
`ItemView` and `OrderView`. Below is a picture showing what I'm trying to represent :

[image]

Data in the black and red form are loaded when the page loads (for now I was only able to get them from `@{ ... }` at the begining of the page.

So when I click on an Item in the red view, it sends an "id" to the green view... Then I edit the green view...

**What I like is to persist data from the black form and from the green form at the same time using a single submit button in the master page**

How could I ever do that ?

I thought I could pass models between view but it seems not to be a good idea..

Answer (score 0):

if it is a render partial. you can do that way :

```
@Html.Partial("ItemView", "Home")
```

if not and if its a actionresult that way

```
 @Html.Action("OrderView", "Home")
```

but you must have a code

```
public ActionResult OrderView(){ return View (); } or puplic PartialView IremView() { return PartiaView(); }
```

Comment: But it would not be based on 3 models...There are 3 models on that page but razor can only suport one model per page... Or do you think I could still call `OrderView(item model1, order model2, invoice model3)` with the submit button ?

Comment: it is possible with ajax.  so like this : $.ajax{ url : '', data:'', success:function(data){ document.getElementByID('resultidiv').innerHtml = data.Value ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use ajax here.

You can wrap you red view into `@using (Ajax.BeginForm` and set `UpdateTargetId` to you green view.

Another approach is to use js to send request on item selection and refresh red view on receiving the response.